# Is there any way to edit the pop-up comments dialog box for Workbox actions?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Right now, this dialog just says "Enter a comment:".  I would like to edit this text or add some new text.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to "core" database and navigate to `/sitecore/system/Dictionary/E/Enter a comment` item. In the Phrase field of this item place a string you'd like to see instead of default "Enter a comment:". Save the item - and try it out!

Update: BTW, the same technique is used for translations. If you switch to the Danish version of the item, you can see the Danish text in the Phrase field. If Phrase field is empty (like for English version of the item by default), the Key field is returned instead.